# Binding files from ClientBin folder into a ComboBox in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, combobox

I was wondering if it was possible to bind some filenames in a given directory of the ClientBin folder to a ComboBox.

I'm working on this application that has a video Tutorials section. I've got a comobox that lets the user select which tutorial video they wish to see.

Right now not all the videos are completed (it's a bit time consuming) and I would like to deploy the application. It would be great if I could work on the videos later on and just upload them to my ClientBin/Videos directory and have my Silverlight App pick them up automatically without me having to go into the XAML and add the new videos to the ComboBox.

Anyone know if this is feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bet.  You'll need directory browsing turned on in IIS, though.  Once you've done that,

- Use the WebClient's DownloadString functionality and issue a request to /Videos.
- Parse the result, and you have a list of files